# Using progress indicator with sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: objective-c

I am downloading a pdf file with sendSynchronousRequest is there a way to implement a progress indicator with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are yousing synchronous request you can't implement it. 
I'd recommend you to use `+connectionWithRequest:delegate:` method and set your controller as the delegate. In this case to track progress you can use `-connection:didReceiveData:` delegate's method.

Comment: I had a feeling I couldn't implement it into the synchronous request. Thanks for confirming my thoughts.